# 'A callback is required to get a store menu' error appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback

When I ran the code without the variable 'idd' the code would run. but when I attached a variable rather than a static number to the 'Store({ ID:  })', it would give me an error.

```
var idd;

function getid(){
    var pizzapi = require('dominos');
    pizzapi.Util.findNearbyStores(
        '07054',
        'Delivery',
        function(storeData){
            console.log(storeData.result.Stores[0].StoreID);
            idd = storeData.result.Stores[0].StoreID;
        }
    );
}

function menu(){
  var pizzapi = require('dominos');
  var myStore = new pizzapi.Store({ ID: idd });

  myStore.getMenu(
      function(storeData){
          console.log(storeData);
      }
  );
}

getid();
menu();
```

Message:

```
{
  success: false,
  message: 'A callback is required to get a store menu'
}
```

Comment: show the error and show the Store function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)